# Keeping Text positioned correctly when resizing div with backround image: contain

Tags: css

I have a background image that needs to resize and maintain aspect ratio (contain) and keep text within it at the same level in the image as it's resizing.

```
.skyimage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 841px;
    background: url("image.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

What's the best way to position text so that it stays aligned (as much as possible) with the same point in the image as it's resizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">CenteredCenteredCenteredCenteredCenteredCenteredCenteredCentered</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you aligning the text? You could try flexbox and use:

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
```

(sorry couldn't provide a fiddle, using my mobilel